# How to get max key out of a very big dictionary

Tags: python-2.7

I have made a dictionary which contains a huge amount of data. I have plotted the keys(y-axia) vs the values(x-axis) out of it. I have got few peaks in that plot. I want to get the keys and their corresponding values for those peaks out of that plot.

I have used this
import operator
max(dA.iteritems(), key = operator.itemgetter(1))[0]

but it only gives me one max value.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

To get all instances of the max value, use this code:

```
a=max(dA.iteritems(), key = operator.itemgetter(1)) #finds the max value
print [b for b in dA.keys() if dA[b]==a[1]]
#the above line iterates through the keys of dA and returns all
#x values where the y associated with that x is equal to a[1], the max value.
```

However, you need to find the peaks. What you do is:

```
a=dA.items()
result=[] #we will store the answer in here
for i in range(1, len(a)):
    if a[i-1][1]<a[i][1] and a[i][1]>a[i+1][1]: #if there is a peak
        result.append(a[i]) #add the x-value and the y-value to the list
print result
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import operator

def dict_top_n_subset(d, n):
    """Given a dict d, return a subset dict with the top n value"""
    n = min(n, len(d))
    return dict(sorted(d.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[-n:])
```

Example use:

```
>>> d={1:5, 2:10, 3:7, 4:73, 5:6}
>>> dict_top_n_subset(d, 1)
{4: 73}
>>> dict_top_n_subset(d, 2)
{2: 10, 4: 73}
>>> dict_top_n_subset(d, 3)
{2: 10, 3: 7, 4: 73}
```

Keep in mind this may use a lot of memory (2x?) if your dict is huge, in which case you might want to manually iterate and keep track of your own peaks -- but that's a lot harder than 2 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

```
import heapq
import operator
dict(heapq.nlargest(n, data_dict.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)))
```

Use [`heapq.nlargest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) to efficiently find the `n` highest key-value pairs, ordered by value.